Changing SpatiaLite 0/1 to GeoJSON False/True with ogr2ogr
SpatiaLite doesn't have a native bool type; instead, false and true are encoded as 0 and 1.
Say I have a table like



id
is_exempt
geometry




1
0
<geom>


2
1
<geom>



I'd like to produce a GeoJSON file where the features have properties like
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": 1, "is_exempt": false} ...}

Is there a way to do this with ogr2ogr?

Use -sql with CASE https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_case_expression.
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -sql "select id, geom, CASE WHEN is_exempt=0 THEN 'false' WHEN is_exempt=1 THEN 'true' END AS is_exempt from table_name" boolean.json input.sqlite


Thanks, corrected now.

In addition to using the SQLite CASE Expression, the WITH Clause can be used to create a common table expression (CTE) to do the mapping of 0/1 to false/true in a more declarative manner.
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -sql "WITH map(i,b) AS (VALUES (0, 'false'),(1, 'true')) SELECT id, b AS is_exempt FROM table_name t, map m where t.is_exempt = m.i" boolean.json sample.db

